# Mac Outlook 16.77 using Addin not fetching attachment format/content properly

Tags: javascript, outlook, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

With Mac Outlook addin during our recent testing, we found that Mac Outlook 16.77 (23091003) doesn’t fetch attachment format/content properly using the JS API.
While the same JS addin fetches this properly using same manifest/JS in Outlook 16.75.1 (23071400)

```
            Attached is a reference to what happens when we access “result.value.format” variable when user sends a mail with attachment and our addin tries to get attachment details.

            This can be easily reproduced by referring to sample code here
            https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.mailboxenums.attachmentcontentformat?view=outlook-js-preview
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9Dst.png)

Let me know if you require any further information.

Getting attachment format/content properly using Javascript API on all outlook versions

Comment: The issue is fixed, can you please confirm.

Comment: Yes. It is fixed and we didn't need to update our outlook app or manifest or javascript.

Could you please let us know how to handle this case in our code so that we dont block the user to send an email. We have 1000s of machines on which the addin will be deployed and users will complain if they are not able to send a mail.

Is exception handling better or any other approach to 
1) know the problem
2) allow users in sending mail 


try{
} catch (err) {
}


what is the root cause of this problem ?